# Footnotes: fix code

Tags: hyperref, numbering, footnotes

The aim is to footnote something without a number. The idea was something like

```
\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{\begingroup\renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}}
```

Given this code at the bottom I have two problems:

1. The footnote with `\blfootnote` has no number but hyperref put some red box without content. This I don't want.
2. The footnotes with `\footnote` have no numbers anymore.

   ```
   \documentclass{scrartcl}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
   \newcommand\blfootnote[1]{\begingroup\renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}}
   \usepackage[ngerman]{varioref}
   \usepackage{hyperref}
   \usepackage[ngerman]{cleveref}
   \begin{document}
   \blfootnote{should be without number and is without number}
   \footnote{should be with number but is without number}
   \end{document}
   ```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: You say `\begingroup`, but you forgot the corresponding `\endgroup`! ;-)  See Werner’s answer, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

For `\footnote`s *without* a number, just use `\footnotetext` with a minor adjustment of the printing of the footnote number:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[paperheight=20\baselineskip]{geometry}% Just for this example

\newcommand{\blfootnote}[1]{{\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\roman{footnote}}\footnotetext[0]{#1}}}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\blfootnote{should be without number and is without number}
\footnote{should be with number}

\end{document}
```

`\footnotetext[<num>]{<fn>}` sets the footnote `<fn>` with the number `<num>`. If no number is specified, it uses the current footnote number. The definition of `\blfootnote` resets the numbering scheme to `\alph` and forces the footnote number to `0`. And since `\alph` of the number `0` results in a blank entry, not footnote number is printed.

The change inside `\blfootnote` of `\thefootnote` is localized so `\thefootnote` reverts back to the original definition after the macro call.